# How to replace $ currency with Rp (Rupiah) format in Javascript

Tags: javascript

**I have a code below, i want to change/replace currency format from ($) with (Rp.) in js. I have tired with this, anybody can help me?

```
function update_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("$","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
  });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html("$"+total);
  $('#total').html("$"+total);

  update_balance();
}

function update_balance() {
  var due = $("#total").html().replace("$","") - $("#paid").val().replace("$","");
  due = roundNumber(due,2);

  $('.due').html("$"+due);
}

function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
  var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("$","") * row.find('.qty').val();
  price = roundNumber(price,2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("$"+price);

  update_total();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its only html you want to replace you can use

```
replace('$','&#x52;&#x70;')
```

Comment: Okay thank u, although what I mean above is Indonesian Rupiah, not Indian Rupee :)